# Change button background for a short period of time

Tags: android

I want to change the button background color for a short period of time after the button is pressed. The button should regain it's previous condition after that period.
Probably a handler is the correct decision for this problem, unfortunately i didn't found a working example for doing a similar thing.
If anyone can give me a short example of how doing a such thing i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this :

```
public class LaunchActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

private Button yourButton;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      

    yourButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
    yourButton.setOnTouchListener(this); 

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent event) {

final int action = event.getAction();

    if(view.getId()==R.id.yourButton){
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
              yourButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_button_pressed);
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
               Handler handler = new Handler(); 
               handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
               public void run() { 
              yourButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_button_normal); 
           } 
         }, 2000); 

        }
    }
```

}
}

Or with an onClick listener :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    yourButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.first_icon);
    // SLEEP 2 SECONDS HERE ...
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
              yourButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.second_icon); 
         } 
    }, 2000); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define an XML background for your button under `res/drawable/button_background`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_notpressed"/>
</selector>
```

and for use an `ImageButton`

```
<ImageButton
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    ... />
```